# ReactJS: Logic Operator

Tags: reactjs

I have

```
var weightpref = naa?.WeightPref == true || naa.WeightPref == undefined ? 'kg' : 'lb'
```

So basically if naa (an array) has WeightPref set to true or if the field does not exist then it should show kg otherwise show lb.

It doesn't seem to look at the undefined at all. So while I can get it working for simple true/false am also trying to build logic in for if the field hasn't actually been set yet.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the property has the value `undefined`, or if the property itself is `undefined`?

Comment: So, `naa` is an actual array, and it has custom properties like WeightPref? Your usage of `naa?.WeightPref` seems to imply that naa could possibly be undefined/null. If `naa` is undefined, then `naa?.WeightPref` is undefined. So `naa?.WeightPref == true` is false. Since it is false, `||` will evaluate the next part. Then trying `naa.WeightPref` will give you an error.

Comment: Just checking to see if the property itself exists....

Comment: Thats right it is an array - and WeightPref is a boolean field